# jQuery: fading scrollbars plugin

Tags: looking-for-a-script, jquery, plugin

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin which changes the standard scrollbars to those invisible ones only visible during scrolling and then fading away. This is probably best known from mobile devices, the new Mac OS X Lion browser, or the facebook notification area / chat bar.

I need this because when the scrollbars are always shown they take too much space.

Has anyone used this? I've found some examples for styling scrollbars but these are neither  invisible upon loading nor they fade away after usage. Additionally they will not overlap with the content but instead reserve their space from the content area.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two plugins which have a lot of customization options

FleXcroll
http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar

jScrollPane
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Scrollbar with Fade effect
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/30/scrollbar-visibility-with-jscrollpane/
Demo
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ScrollbarVisibility/

Updating again to include jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/peter/WehRv/

Comment: Yep, these are the only two I found, too. Apparently they don't seem to support overlapping the bars with the content.

Comment: I updated to include a jsfiddle plus another fade effect link

Comment: Demos look good but doesn't play well with JqueryUI... Will look into it later... Also, ScrollbarVisibility seems to only support one pane due to its use of global variables.

Comment: I would play with jquery fadein effect with a mouse over event. I'm not that good with jQuery but I would suggest you post these on stack overflow if they don't work and ask for some example code, they're really helpful over there for getting code working